# MAC changing program or daemon?

Tags: networking, daemon

I'm currently have a program which creates a list of all MAC addresses and corresponding names and IP addresses on my network.

I was wondering if it's possible (theoretically) to create a background program which, every hour, would change your MAC address based on the list you provide. The list would continuously be updated by the already stated program.

I'm good with Python and Batch, but I'm running a Mac system right now (which is what I want to implement this program on) and have little knowledge of bash when it comes to the network itself, or of creating background tasks that are time sensitive.

If this is too broad of a question, please do let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this with a simple script, and periodically run it using `cron`.

Here is an example of how to change your MAC address from a shell script (adapted from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Changing_Your_MAC_Address/Linux))

```
#NETWORKING="/etc/init.d/networking"   # On some systems
NETWORKING="service network"           # On my Fedora 16 box

$NETWORKING stop
ifconfig eth0 hw ether 02:01:02:03:04:08
$NETWORKING start
```

So you'd need to come up with a way to randomize that MAC address.

Then, use `crontab -e` to add it to your crontab.  Here is a [quick reference for crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference).

Here's some python to generate a random MAC address and change it. Only the MAC generation has been tested (for obvious reasons). Also note, you may want to limit the range on some of the bytes in the MAC address, but that is outside the scope of my answer.

```
from subprocess import call
import random

mac = [random.randint(0, 0xFF) for i in range(6)]    
macstr = ':'.join(['{:02X}'.format(x) for x in mac])
print 'Changing MAC address to', macstr

call(['service', 'network', 'stop')
call(['ifconfig', 'eth0', 'hw', 'ether', macstr])
call(['service', 'network', 'start')
```

Comment: That's what I'm having trouble with -- randomizing that MAC address from a preexisting list. I can't load it in as data or anything because it's just a bash script... Thanks for the reference on cron though!

Comment: I would probably consider doing it in something like python then

Comment: How would I set that program as a background process? 
I don't want to randomize the MAC address, I want it taken from a list randomly. So every half hour, say, it takes a MAC address listed (each on new line) on a text file and sets it as the new MAC address. 

That program itself (now that I know the 'call' method) is pretty straightforward, my problem is setting a python program as a daemon.

My thought was to create it in python, then create a bash script to call that python program, set that bash script as a daemon which activates the python program every x amount of time.